# Keep my Apple ID, but delete individual iCloud services and data (for example the mailbox @icloud.com)

Tags: icloud, email, apple-id, privacy

When I type in DuckDuckGo something like *How to permanently delete an Apple ID account* I get lots of hits. But it will delete the complete Apple ID.

- I wish only to delete the mailbox @icloud.com and @me.com. I no longer wish to have an Apple provided mail service.
- I also wish to delete my account (and all data) on individual iCloud services (example iCloud Keychain).

Comment: What would your Apple ID's email address be if you delete the iCloud.com address ?

Comment: What's the point of deleting the email address?

Comment: You can't delete an icloud.com email address without deleting the linked Apple ID because an icloud.com email address **is** an Apple ID. If you delete the former, you delete the latter. If you haven't used your Apple ID to purchase anything, delete the account and create a new one. If you have purchased content, call Apple Support and request a purchase transfer to a new, non-icloud.com Apple ID (I don't know if that works, YMMV). According to https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT202667, if you use an @icloud.com email address as your Apple ID, you can’t change it to a third party email address.

Comment: What process did you find to delete an AppleID? I was under the impression Apple still didn’t do that. You can remove the account from devices, you can delete your data. It’s not clear what process you seek here unless this is just two distinct questions about purging the iCloud Keychain and setting up a purge / block on incoming mails.

Comment: @bmike You can delete your Apple ID at https://privacy.apple.com "Permanently delete your account and associated data from all Apple apps and services."

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't remove the email functionality from a icloud.com or me.com adress. What you can do instead is to

- log into icloud.com in any browser
- go to Mail
- click on the cog wheel at bottom left and select Settings (first entry in the menu)
- set auto-forwarding of all mails to your new email adress

Answer (score 4):

This is impossible as clearly stated on [Apple's website](https://support.apple.com/en-gb/HT202667):

> ## How to change your Apple ID if it ends with @icloud.com, @me.com or @mac.com
>
> If you use an @icloud.com, @mac.com or @me.com email address as your Apple ID, **you can’t change it to a third-party email address**.

That is your Apple ID so you can't change it, the only real alternative is to create a new Apple ID.